# play not extracting code

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play-2.0. I have the following code snippet, where I'm trying to publish a list of products along with corresponding links. For some reason, the code path that I'm using currently outputs HTML of the form: @routes.Products.details(x.ean.toString()). Upon commenting this and uncommenting the commented path, I the link generation is fine. Could someone please explain what's going on?

```
@(list: List[Product])(implicit lang: Lang)
@main( Messages( "application.name" ) ){


<ul>
@*
@for(product <- list){
  <li>
    <a href="@routes.Products.details(product.ean.toString())">
      @product.name
    </a>
  </li>
}
*@

@list.map( x =>
  <li>
    <a href="@routes.Products.details(x.ean.toString())">
      {x.name}
    </a>
  </li>

)

</ul>

}
```

EDIT: fixed the href in part that doesn't work.

Comment: Is your `Products` controller in a sub directory? If yes you have to add the name of the sub directory before routes: `@productDir.routes.Products.detail(product.ean)`. Keep in mind that you have to rename your variable `product` if your folder called product as well.

Comment: Sorry, the question didn't come out right, both the href's are exactly same in the view. Let me correct.

Comment: @BlithE: I've corrected the href now. Products controller is in the controllers directory.

Comment: So your part with the map doesn't work, right? To bad I never used a map in a template before, so I can't help you here. But why do you use {} in `{x.name}`? Is this to access the variable? Have you tried that `{routes.Products.details(x.ean.toString())}`?

Comment: @BlithE: Thanks for the response. I use {} because x.name and @(x.name) don't work. I tried {routes.p.d.(x.e.t())) as well, but that doesn't work either. So in the innerHTML, only {} works, and in the href link, nothing works.

Comment: @BlithE Also, the way you say it, isn't there a catchall rule or you think that all language constructs work differently?

Comment: I don't know a map construct should work, because I never used it. But I guess @routes should also work there. If the for loop works correctly why don't you use this instead of the map?

Comment: Because I want to understand what's going on.. :)